# Visual Studio 2022 npm package manager

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm

I have this situation in node.js projects in Visual Studio 2022.
My npm package manager shows all packages regardless of their state (npm-node-explorer shows all the sub-dependencies of all the packages), as shown in the picture

[image: npm explorer]

The thing I don't understand about this "issue" is the fact that in other projects I don't see those "Installed, but not explicitly listed in package.json" npm packages.
Here's an example of a project:

[image: npm explorer 2]

Is there a way to see only installed and listed in package.json packages?

Comment: I found out that the "problem" is that **nodejstools** (Visual Studio npm package manager) uses the **"\_requiredBy"** tag written in **package.json** files inside the dependencies folders in node_modules.
Newer versions of node.js/npm have deprecated all tags that **start with "\_"** in **package.json** files, so nodejstools can't correctly render the dependencies tree.
A work around seems to be possible by **manually writing** that tag in the files.